# Buffered Reader for a socket is never ready

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, java-threads

Just to be completely transparent, this is for an assignment.

There is more to do, but at the moment I'm just trying to get the following:

1. Node A reads in from a text file
2. Node A sends text file (minus the first line) to Node B using a socket
3. Node B read in from said socket, and prints it out to the console

However, right now, it seems that either the information isn't being sent, or it's not being read correctly by Node B.

In my main class, I set up the nodes like this:

```
NodeA nodeA = new NodeA();
NodeB nodeB = new NodeB();

new Thread(nodeA).start();
new Thread(nodeB).start();
```

In node A, I do this:

```
//Open a socket for talking with NodeB
Socket mySocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNum);

//Set up the socket's output
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream(), true);

//Loop through the lines of the confA file, writing them to the socket
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
while (line != null)
{
    //Write the line to the socket, get the next line
    out.println(line); //updated to println, this flushes and fixes another problem
    out.flush();
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}

//Close the socket
mySocket.close();
```

Note that Node A's loop works fine. It doesn't loop forever and does go through the intended lines of text when I tested with print statements.

Then, on Node B's end: **Updated to show current Node B code**

```
//Open the socket 
ServerSocket mySocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);
Socket connectionSocket = mySocket.accept();

//Set up a reader on the socket to get what's coming from it
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

String line = in.readLine(); //hang occurs here

while(line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = in.readLine();;
}
```

However, in.ready() is never true. I've tried waiting around for that to happen using a while loop but it never occurs.

I'm really not sure why. I have no idea if I set up the socket correctly, if I set up the server correctly, if I am listening correctly, etc.

I just figured that making B into a server which is listening for A made the most sense. I hope that's right. It looks similar to what I saw some other examples on SO did.

Thank you for any and all help. I'm extremely unfamiliar with sockets, ports, listening and otherwise, so forgive me if I don't understand your suggestions at first. I'll do my best to understand it as I go.

I refrained from adding the whole of the code to hopefully make it more readable and clear where the issue might be, but if you need more information just feel free to ask and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: 1) Each time `ServerSocket.accept()` returns you have a connected socket established between server and client. For *that* connection you do *not* call `ServerSocket.accept()` again. 2) In your client, the PrintWriter buffers data internally. If you want the result of calling `out.print(line);` to be seen immediately on the network then you must call `out.flush()` as the next statement.

Comment: All `ready()` does is return whether the next read will return immediately.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server must first get from the ServerSocket the Socket to the client.

```
connectionSocket = mySocket.accept();
```

The server thread will be sleep till a client causes it to accept the connectionSocket.

*Then* you can read from the connectionSocket. `ready` not being needed.

As this is an assignment, I leave the rest to you.

---

By the way a typical server would do:

```
for (;;) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    ... pass the socket to a thread from a pool of threads
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but a few things are still very confusing about this. Once the server has finished waiting and the client has connected, I shouldn't need to do another .accept(), right? I tried changing my code so as to only have the initial .accept, but I still can't seem to be able to read from the socket, it just hangs on readLine() forever.

Comment: You should only have one `ServerSocket.accept` yielding a Socket to read from.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the code with the removal of the extra .accepts() an the removal of the .ready() and now show where the hang is occuring.

Comment: Okay, you are there. At the client do `println` instead of `print`. This flushes the buffer to the output. A `new PrintWriter(..., true)` automatically flushes on println. Good night at my side.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working perfectly now. I was wondering why the result was getting smashed into one line when I tried out.flush(). Now I can remove that.

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine will return the line _without_ line ending. Hence the need for a println.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that ready just means that if you call a read, it won't block.  You can see the code that gets executed if you look up the function on grepcode:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.ready%28%29

A ready thread just means it's not going to block, which is useful when you want to ensure that your thread isn't going to get tied up, but doesn't really tell you if you have buffer or not.

What you want to do is perform the readline, as a blocking call, until the data is consumed.  If you don't want this blocking your current thread, then spin off a new consumer thread specific for this reading that can block.

Also, make sure that you're ending your send communication with either a closed socket or flush to indicate to the consuming stream when it is complete. And you only need to socket accept once per open/close session.

Comment: I don't mind the read blocking my current thread, that shouldn't be a problem at all. I tried changing my code to only have a single .accept() initially and change in.ready() to just make sure that the line returned from readLine() isn't null (there are more lines to move to read in) but it's still hanging on the initial readLine() I try to do.

Comment: Readline requires an end to the string, it's looking for a \n EOL or closed socket.  If it hangs, it means it's waiting for more data.  You can close the socket on the writer at the end of writing as a test to confirm.

Comment: Thank you. I tested with putting a mySocket.close(); at the end of Node A's code. No luck yet though. Would I need to close it on the other end as well?